# How can I get my local host and port in a Java servlet method init()?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, request

How do I retrieve the port number in the init method.
In a `doGet` or `doPost` I can use:

```
request.getLocalPort();
```

but in the `init()` method there is no request object.

I don't want to configure it, I want the port dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There is no such thing as 'the' port. The container could be listening on any number of ports and any number of IP addresses.

Comment: Ok, you're right. It is not my host what is important, it is how the client make the request what is important.